# Access- Email with Attached PDF report

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I have a database which currently emails all staff who have a record showing as overdue.

I also have a report which is automatically saving as a PDF each day showing any overdue records.

I would like the email which is being sent to attach the ***newest*** PDF report from the folder of saved reports.

Currently I have the code below for the attachment part of my email but I am unsure on how to get this to do what I want, as above:

```
strAtt = Array("J:\performancereview\coaching\ " & ".pdf")
```

Any ideas would be appreciated? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this on an individual entry basis or a loop of all staff?

We do something similar in our system. We operate it on a query loop.

The general idea of how we do it are:

```
Dim pdfFileName as string
Dim permail as string

'Open an Rst Record Set

pdfFileName = "Y:\Personnell\" & rst!ID & newfolder & ".pdf" ' Rst!ID is from the query.
permail = rst![email]

'Save the report from access report using the pdfFileName name construct.

               With oMail
                    .to = permail
                    .htmlBody = "Email Body" ' Enter your email body here
                    .Subject = "Email Subject" ' Enter email subject here
                    .Attachments.Add (pdfFileName)
                    .Send


                End With
rst.MoveNext

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way is to use the date in the file name.
If you include the date in the name of the pdf eg. overdue01012016.pdf each day

```
stratt = "reportfolderpath\" & "overdue" & replace(date(),"/","") & ".pdf"
```